# Date time comparisons

Tags: mysql

1. I have a date column for ex: 03/08/2011 & i need to make that as end of the day ie. 03/08/2011 12:00:00 in UTC time format & then add some integer value in minutes say for ex:10 (in mins)-> 03/08/2011 12:10:00. This value is used as end value.
2. There will be some start value like for ex: 03/07/2011 22:10:00 & i need to get current date time in UTC, do a comparison to see & return 1 if current date time falls between start & end value else return 0.
3. All in a single select query in mysql.

Thanks.

Comment: You need to use an actual date-stamp if you want it in pure SQL. `03/08/2011` is wrong. `2011-03-08` is right.

Comment: Reference: [11.7. Date and time functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html)

Comment: Can you show some data you have and sample of what you are overall expecting it to look like?

Comment: It will be great if someone gets some sample example.

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear exactly what you need, but I'll give you a couple of specific examples that should help.

1) Converting a MM/DD/YYYY string to a date and adding 10 minutes to it:

```
mysql> SELECT STR_TO_DATE('03/08/2011', '%m/%d/%Y') + INTERVAL 10 MINUTE;
+------------------------------------------------------------+
| STR_TO_DATE('03/08/2011', '%m/%d/%Y') + INTERVAL 10 MINUTE |
+------------------------------------------------------------+
| 2011-03-08 00:10:00                                        |
+------------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

2) Getting the current timestamp in UTC:

```
mysql> SELECT UTC_TIMESTAMP();
+---------------------+
| UTC_TIMESTAMP()     |
+---------------------+
| 2011-03-08 20:33:53 |
+---------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: Thanks, but i need the time added in utc time STR_TO_DATE('03/08/2011', '%m/%d/%Y') + INTERVAL 10 MINUTE |
+------------------------------------------------------------+
| 2011-03-08 00:10:00            -> 00:10:00 is in local time, i need in UTC time.

Comment: What time zone are you in? -12:00? You can use `CONVERT_TZ()` to convert form your time zone to UTC. For example, `select convert_tz(STR_TO_DATE('03/08/2011', '%m/%d/%Y'),'-12:00','+00:00') + interval 10 minute;`

Comment: You actually don't even have to use your TZ: take Ike's advice and use 'SYSTEM' as your TZ: `select convert_tz(STR_TO_DATE('03/08/2011', '%m/%d/%Y'),'SYSTEM','+00:00') + interval 10 minute`